# How can I show that this equation is true?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

Is it possible to show that for $m \ge 1$, I can always find two positive integers $n$ and $c$ to satisfy the following formula?

$$\frac{{n+c\choose 2}}{{n\choose 2}+n{c+1\choose 2}+c(n-1)+{c+1\choose 3}} \times (1+c) \gt m$$

Comment: It might be possible to show that. But why on earth would one _want to_ show that? In other words, what is the motivation for your question?

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen Well it's part of a homework question:

"The diameter of a graph is defined as the maximum distance between any pair of nodes in the graph. The average distance in a graph is the average distance over all pairs of nodes in the graph. Describe how you could construct a graph in which the diameter exceeds the average distance by as large a factor as you’d like."

I came up with an approach and to show that it works, I need to show that the above is true.  I purposely didn't show the context because I did want to just post the question on Stack Exchange.

Comment: Well I can assure you that in order to answer the question about the graphs, you don't need to show the above equality; maybe you should try another approach? In any case, it would seem that what you need to prove is an inequality (diameter exceeds a multiple of the average distance), not an equality.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen Thanks for the tip.  I didn't include the last part of the question because I ran out of space.  It says: "(That is, for every number c, can you produce a graph in which the diameter is more than c times as large as the average distance?)".  Now that you have pointed it out, I've re-read the question and I think you are right!

Answer (score 1):

Put $n=c^2$. Then the expression on the left hand side reduces (after some calculations) to something like
$$
\frac{3 (c+1) \left(c^2+c-1\right)}{6 c^2+4 c-7},
$$
which diverges to $\infty$ as $c\to\infty$.